# Why can Cheat Engine access a memory location but my own program cannot?

Tags: c, memory

When I use [Cheat Engine](https://www.cheatengine.org) to inspect the memory of a game I see a particular value at address 0x009FF414. When I try to read that same location with a little C program (see below), I get a runtime error.

Why can Cheat Engine access that address even though my program cannot? What would I need to do in my program to read that memory?

My Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int *ptr = 0x009FF414;
  printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume to be able to read a random address?

Comment: moreover this is very well a UB

Comment: i think  cheat engine software do it...

Comment: What platform are you compiling this for? Generally this is not valid C code. (due to address space randomization), but some implementations do provide access to fixed memory regions. In order to know which applies, you have to know what you are targeting.

Comment: how can do it? for example for special app or software that is running.

Comment: You want to read the memory of another program?

Comment: yeah i want do it.

Comment: `how can do it?` learn a lot about OS-es, languages etc etc. The answers will come with time

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what is being asked. I think the question has value. (Cheat Engine somehow attaches to a running process which enables it to read that program's memory, basically in the fashion of a debugger, but  (1) I'm unaware of the mechanism and (2) I'm curious what needed to be done to do that in my own program.)

Comment: @0___________ Are you sure this is a duplicate ? In this one OP is try understand why with one software you can but not with the other. It looks like the duplicate is a subset of the answer that OP is looking for

Comment: @dreamcrash Note that I heavily edited the question to address the underlying issue.

Comment: Changed dupe to more relevant.

Comment: @0___________ Ah, that dup is indeed relevant. It would be nice though to have a working minimal example showing how to do that.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Thanks for pointing that out I have miss that

Answer (score 0):

A 32 bit micro processor can address about 4GB of memory. This does not mean all 4GB are mapped into the current address space. What is mapped depends both on the operating system and whether ASLR is being used. Processes can also map more RAM or other resources using APIs like mmap or VirtualAlloc. So what may work in one process, may not work somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

The memory address you are trying to read may be used by another process which you cannot access from your program.
For better understanding of how operating system prevents one program from accessing another programs memory you can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection).

Comment: It is a comment, not the answer

Comment: I misunderstood his question. I thought he was asking why he can't read that address using that C program.